# Download Files Async

Tags: c#, file, download

My code is something like this:

```
WebClient sz_GetConf = new WebClient();
        #region get_FilesInReleaseManifest
        if (File.Exists("release_manifest"))
        {
            string[] files = File.ReadAllLines("release_manifest");
            foreach (string fileName in files)
                if (File.Exists("WoWFolder/" + fileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                    string itemToDownload = urlPath;
                    itemToDownload += fileName;
                    sz_GetConf.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(sz_GetConf_DownloadProgressChanged);
                    sz_GetConf.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(sz_GetConf_DownloadFileCompleted);
                    sz_GetConf.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://someurl.com/dl/"+fileName), fileName);
                }
        #endregion
```

When I try to compile I receive the error:

> "No source available No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame.
>   The source code could not be displayed."

What should I do?

Error image: [Click me!](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xm0b9z&s=8#.Ux19jWKSxc0)

Comment: You're sure you see that at *compilation* time? Where is the error shown? That sounds more like a debugging error...

Comment: I've added a image with the error.

Comment: And you got that *just* by building? Not by trying to *run* the code?

Comment: By simple debugging(F5)

Comment: Ah, so it's *not* when you try to compile - it's when you try to run. I suggest you edit your question appropriately. Now, does it stop with an exception? Is there anything in the output window?

Comment: Nothing... no error no warning. The only problem is that this frame appears.

Comment: In that case I'd just close the window - it may be left over from a previous debugging session. If everything is working fine, I think it's reasonable to just ignore it.